# What may cause this hashcode looping hibernate error?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I get this strange hashCode looping error when trying to update an order.
I'm not able to share all the code, but I can share snippets by request.
Any ideas what is wrong?
I suspect a Spring Hibernate issue, but I can't find it.
Anyone got this before?

I tried have a look at all the cascadetype.all etc, but I can't find the issue.

```
Hibernate: insert into dbo.orderrow_aud (revtype, price, status, usages, work_title, price_list_id, usage_order_id, work_type_id, orderrow_id, rev) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select orderrowcr0_.alis_id as alis_id1_57_, orderrowcr0_.orderrow_id as orderrow2_57_ from dbo.orderrow_creator orderrowcr0_ where orderrowcr0_.orderrow_id=?
Hibernate: select orderrowcr0_.alis_id as alis_id1_57_0_, orderrowcr0_.orderrow_id as orderrow2_57_0_ from dbo.orderrow_creator orderrowcr0_ where orderrowcr0_.alis_id=? and orderrowcr0_.orderrow_id=?
Hibernate: insert into dbo.orderrow_creator (alis_id, orderrow_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: update dbo.orderrow set price=?, price_list_id=?, status=?, terms=?, usage_order_id=?, usages=?, work_title=?, work_type_id=? where orderrow_id=?
Hibernate: select worktypeen0_.work_type_id as work_typ1_92_0_, worktypeen0_.work_type_description as work_typ2_92_0_, worktypeen0_.work_type_name as work_typ3_92_0_ from dbo.work_type worktypeen0_ where worktypeen0_.work_type_id=?
Hibernate: insert into revinfo (revtstmp) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into dbo.orderrow_creator_aud (revtype, alis_id, orderrow_id, rev) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into dbo.orderrow_aud (revtype, price, status, usages, work_title, price_list_id, usage_order_id, work_type_id, orderrow_id, rev) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select usageorder0_.distribution_type_id as distribu1_81_, usageorder0_.usage_order_id as usage_or2_81_ from dbo.usage_order_distribution_type usageorder0_ where usageorder0_.usage_order_id=?
Hibernate: select usageorder0_.distribution_type_id as distribu1_81_4_, usageorder0_.usage_order_id as usage_or2_81_4_, distributi1_.distribution_type_id as distribu1_41_0_, distributi1_.description as descript2_41_0_, distributi1_.name as name3_41_0_, usagetyped2_.distribution_type_id as distribu2_84_6_, usagetyped2_.usage_type_distribution_type_id as usage_ty1_84_6_, usagetyped2_.usage_type_distribution_type_id as usage_ty1_84_1_, usagetyped2_.distribution_type_id as distribu2_84_1_, usagetyped2_.usage_type_id as usage_ty3_84_1_, usageorder3_.usage_order_id as usage_or1_79_2_, usageorder3_.usage_order_case_id as usage_o11_79_2_, usageorder3_.usage_order_status as usage_o12_79_2_, usageorder3_.deficit_addition as deficit_2_79_2_, usageorder3_.edition_size as edition_3_79_2_, usageorder3_.revision_id as revision4_79_2_, usageorder3_.usage_order_date as usage_or5_79_2_, usageorder3_.usage_order_license_date as usage_or6_79_2_, usageorder3_.usage_order_notes as usage_or7_79_2_, usageorder3_.usage_order_title as usage_or8_79_2_, usageorder3_.usage_order_total as usage_or9_79_2_, usageorder3_.usage_order_vat_rate as usage_o10_79_2_, usageorder3_.usage_type_id as usage_t13_79_2_, aliscaseen4_.alis_case_id as alis_cas1_8_3_, aliscaseen4_.agreement_file as agreemen2_8_3_, aliscaseen4_.alis_case_type_id as alis_cas7_8_3_, aliscaseen4_.alis_case_user_id as alis_cas3_8_3_, aliscaseen4_.assignee as assignee4_8_3_, aliscaseen4_.alis_case_status as alis_cas8_8_3_, aliscaseen4_.status_comment as status_c5_8_3_, aliscaseen4_.update_ts as update_t6_8_3_ from dbo.usage_order_distribution_type usageorder0_ left outer join dbo.distribution_type distributi1_ on usageorder0_.distribution_type_id=distributi1_.distribution_type_id left outer join dbo.usage_type_distribution_type usagetyped2_ on distributi1_.distribution_type_id=usagetyped2_.distribution_type_id left outer join dbo.usage_order usageorder3_ on usageorder0_.usage_order_id=usageorder3_.usage_order_id left outer join dbo.alis_case aliscaseen4_ on usageorder3_.usage_order_case_id=aliscaseen4_.alis_case_id where usageorder0_.distribution_type_id=? and usageorder0_.usage_order_id=?
Hibernate: insert into dbo.usage_order_distribution_type (distribution_type_id, usage_order_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: select casetypeen0_.case_type_id as case_typ1_28_0_, casetypeen0_.case_type_description as case_typ2_28_0_ from dbo.case_type casetypeen0_ where casetypeen0_.case_type_id=?
2021-06-14 10:35:00,044 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
2021-06-14 10:35:00,055 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter : Uncaught exception thrown
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:67) ~[brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at se.humanit.alisia.security.filter.UserStatusFilter.doFilterInternal(UserStatusFilter.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.3.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.ExceptionLoggingFilter.doFilter(ExceptionLoggingFilter.java:50) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at brave.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:84) ~[brave-instrumentation-servlet-5.10.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletAutoConfiguration.java:138) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.2.2.RELEASE.jar:2.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at se.humanit.alisia.security.filter.SimpleCorsFilter.doFilter(SimpleCorsFilter.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.CaseTypeEntity$HibernateProxy$C5moJv8I.hashCode(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.AlisCaseEntity.hashCode(AlisCaseEntity.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.UsageOrderEntity.hashCode(UsageOrderEntity.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.AlisCaseEntity.hashCode(AlisCaseEntity.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.UsageOrderEntity.hashCode(UsageOrderEntity.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.AlisCaseEntity.hashCode(AlisCaseEntity.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.UsageOrderEntity.hashCode(UsageOrderEntity.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.AlisCaseEntity.hashCode(AlisCaseEntity.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.UsageOrderEntity.hashCode(UsageOrderEntity.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.AlisCaseEntity.hashCode(AlisCaseEntity.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    
                        ..removed hundreds of rows of this same looping issue..
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.UsageOrderEntity.hashCode(UsageOrderEntity.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.AlisCaseEntity.hashCode(AlisCaseEntity.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.UsageOrderEntity.hashCode(UsageOrderEntity.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at se.humanit.alisia.entity.AlisCaseEntity.hashCode(AlisCaseEntity.java:15) ~[classes/:na]
2021-06-14 10:35:00,259 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2021-06-14 10:35:00,263 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2021-06-14 10:35:00,280 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [application/json, text/plain, */*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2021-06-14 10:35:00,281 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor : Writing [{timestamp=Mon Jun 14 10:35:00 CEST 2021, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, message=, path=/p (truncated)...]
2021-06-14 10:35:00,302 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 500
```

AlisCaseEntity:

```
    package se.humanit.alisia.entity;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import se.humanit.alisia.View.Unrestricted;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "ALIS_CASE", schema = "dbo")
public class AlisCaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Audited
    @JsonView(Unrestricted.class)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "NATIVE")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "NATIVE", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "ALIS_CASE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer alisCaseId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "notedCase", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<CaseNote> alisCaseNotes = new ArrayList<>();

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TS")
    private Timestamp updateTs;

    @Audited
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ALIS_CASE_TYPE_ID")
    private CaseTypeEntity alisCaseType;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "ALIS_CASE_USER_ID")
    private Integer alisCaseUserId;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "ASSIGNEE")
    private Integer assignee;

    @Audited
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ALIS_CASE_STATUS")
    private AlisiaStatusEntity status;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "STATUS_COMMENT")
    private String statusComment;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "alisCase", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private UsageOrderEntity usageOrder;

    public AlisCaseEntity(final Integer alisCaseId) {
        this.alisCaseId = alisCaseId;
    }

    public void addNote(final CaseNote note) {
        alisCaseNotes.add(note);
        note.setNotedCase(this);
    }

    /** Column to hold case agreement link   */
    @Column(name = "AGREEMENT_FILE")
    private String agreement;


}
```

UsageOrderEntity:

```
package se.humanit.alisia.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.envers.Audited;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "USAGE_ORDER", schema = "dbo")
public class UsageOrderEntity {

    @Id
    @Audited
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "NATIVE")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "NATIVE", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "USAGE_ORDER_ID")
    private Integer usageOrderId;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "USAGE_ORDER_TITLE")
    private String usageOrderTitle;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "USAGE_ORDER_NOTES")
    private String usageOrderNotes;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "USAGE_ORDER_LICENSE_DATE")
    private Timestamp usageOrderLicenseDate;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "USAGE_ORDER_DATE")
    private Timestamp usageOrderDate;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "USAGE_ORDER_VAT_RATE")
    private Double usageOrderVatRate;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "USAGE_ORDER_TOTAL")
    private Double usageOrderTotal;

    @Audited
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USAGE_ORDER_CASE_ID")
    private AlisCaseEntity alisCase;

    @Audited
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USAGE_TYPE_ID")
    private UsageTypeEntity usageType;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "EDITION_SIZE")
    private Integer editionSize;

    @Audited
    @Column(name = "REVISION_ID")
    private Integer revisionId;

    //This attribute will be added to when total amount is less than 500 SEK * Author/Creator
    @Audited
    @Column(name = "DEFICIT_ADDITION")
    private Double deficitAddition;

    @Audited
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USAGE_ORDER_STATUS")
    private AlisiaStatusEntity alisiaStatusEntity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usageOrderEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<OrderrowEntity> orderRows;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usageOrder", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<UsageOrderDistributionType> usageOrderDistributionTypes;

    @Transient
    private List<Integer> formatIdList;

    @Transient
    private boolean complete;

    public List<String> getFormatIdList() {
        List<String> formatIdList = new ArrayList<>();
        usageOrderDistributionTypes.forEach(format -> formatIdList.add(format.distributionTypeId.toString()));
        return formatIdList;
    }

    public List<String> getFormatTitleList() {
        List<String> formatTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
        usageOrderDistributionTypes.forEach(format -> formatTitleList.add(format.distributionType.getName()));
        return formatTitleList;
    }
}
```

Comment: here is the reason: Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError: null. You'll need to check the code to see if there are obvious issues

Comment: @Stultuske Wow, I actually missed that one! Thanks, I'll debug some more!

Comment: @Danny without showing entity's code it would be difficult to help

Comment: @user15793316 Yeah, and I can't find where or why it does because I never ever use the hashCode() function in the code.

I first thought it was a nullpointer error when Stultuske commented, but I see now it's not.
I will add the Case and Order entities in the original question.